# What are the alternatives for a ListView for a list of days?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to add a view to my app that shows the list of days, with the user being able to select 1 or more days (for calendar-like repetition behavior).

The concept looks like this:

```
Sun | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat
```

I first thought about using a `ListView` but there are 2 problems I can think of with that approach:

- `ListView` only shows items vertically and not horizontally (**by default**).
- There are only 7, static items. I'm not sure whether using a `ListView` is better than just doing it manually (`LinearLayout` with 7 buttons; 1 for each day).

So my question is; what is the best way to achieve it?

*I know there is already a library for an horizontal `ListView`, but it's not maintained anymore, and problems are not being solved, so it's not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of seven CheckBoxes, Switches, or ToggleButtons would work.  Which one you use depends on the visual effect you are trying to achieve.

Because you are not scrolling the list or changing the underlying data (*) the list view adds no real value and considerable complexity to your code

(*) unless you have found a way to add an extra day to the week in which case I'd really like to hear about it!  I need it.

Comment: Thank you. I certainly think the `CheckBox` behavior is what I need. But I'm wondering if I could design it to look something like this: http://www.infragistics.com/uploadedImages/Content/PRODUCTS/jQuery/Controls/Mobile_Input/jquery-check-box-group.png (referring to the list of the car manufacturers at the bottom of the image)

Answer (score 2):

Again, take a look at this "phone schedule" android tutorial [project](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/phone-schedule-schedule-sound-profiles-wifi-bt-more-on-android/).

[image]

Then you can [customize those checkboxes](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-android-checkbox-and-radiobutton-custom-style) the way you exactly want them.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an exact duplicate of the UI you had in mind already created in Android. The closest I found is the new repeat dialog bundled in the May 2013 Google Calendar [update](http://officialandroid.blogspot.fr/2013/05/google-calendar-update-for-android.html) below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I have a clear idea of how I want it to look: an horizontal list of checkboxes, where the buttons with the day as their text are the checkboxes themselves. Kinda like in this image I found on google: http://www.infragistics.com/uploadedImages/Content/PRODUCTS/jQuery/Controls/Mobile_Input/jquery-check-box-group.png (The bottom part)

Comment: @xTCx, Definitely check this out: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-android-checkbox-and-radiobutton-custom-style (it's a partial answer at least). I've updated my answer to reflect this new information as well.

Comment: Hi @Stephan, I did saw this repeat dialog along with the new date/time pickers. They look really good! Unfortunately they are not yet available in the android sdk. I managed to achieve something similar using 7 (styled) buttons which I set as selected using the `setSelected()` method.